# Bad use of sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session

So im having problem with code in php, it drives me crazy..
The thing is, i am making login page, and i have index.php, login.php and dashboard.php.
Login form is in index.php, in login.php it checks if user is in database, and if it is redirect user to dashboard.php, but when i type right user and pass, it redirects me to index.php instead of dashboard.php??

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/new_cms/includes/db.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$btn = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($btn)){
  if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
      echo "You must fill all fields";
  }else{
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
      $query = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql);
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

      if($rows > 0){
           $_SESSION['usr'] = $rows['password'];
           header("Location: dashboard.php");
      }else{
           echo "Invalid login";
      }
   }
}
?>
```

dashboad.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/new_cms/includes/db.php");
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/new_cms/admin/login.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['usr'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    echo "Welcome";
}
?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `login.php` from dashboard this line `include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/new_cms/admin/login.php");`

Comment: You should at least try to do some debugging yourself. Have you checked that `$rows` contains the information you expect? In dashboard.php, what is the content of `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rows is just a number, not an array, since you used mysqli_num_rows. Still you try to get $rows['password'].

instead, fetch the first row of the result and use this to assign to the session variable.

```
if(isset($btn)){
  if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
      echo "You must fill all fields";
  }else{
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
      $query = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql);
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

      if($rows > 0){
           $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
           $_SESSION['usr'] = $user['password'];
           header("Location: dashboard.php");
      }else{
           echo "Invalid login";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot buddy, u really helped me here

Comment: you might also want to consider not putting the password into a session variable for safety reasons. instead, just put the username in there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip man, i really appreciate it, and surely i will do that from now on